# Way to circumvent charge-protection on start?

Tags: oneplus-7-pro

When I plug my old phone in, it says

> Battery too low, charge for a while before powering on.

Is there a method to circumvent this message and power the phone on anyway? It's a sealed phone, and I assume the battery is totally shot.

Comment: Try leaving it plugged on overnight, if possible with a lower rated charger than the one you are using ;if not with existing charger

Answer (score 2):

No, because Android devices are always powered via the battery rather than the AC outlet.

So, your battery must have the least amount of charge to run your phone while it gets topped up by itself.

Comment: There are always exceptions, so I would say that next to all Android devices are powered via battery. I have an old Samsung tablet which runs fine via AC even when I open the device and remove the battery.